# ReactNative and firebase, Real time database when signUp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I build a react native signUp form with this fields (email, password, name, and phone) and I need to add it to the firebase database when user create his account.

I create the signUp function like this:

```js
onSignUpPress() {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
      this.setState({ error: '', loading: true });
      const { email, password } = this.state;
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(() => {
        this.setState({ error: '', loading: false }); 
        navigation.navigate("Profile");
      })
                  .catch(() => {
                      this.setState({ error: 'Authentication failed.', loading: false });
                      console.log("Error creating user:");
                  });
  }
```

and it's work

I need to know how can I add the field to a database

I try this :

```js
writeUserData(uid, name, email, phone) {
    let userId = firebaseApp.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var newUser = {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      phone: phone
    }

  var newUserKey =  firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;
  var updates = {};
updates['/users/' + newUserKey] = newUser;
updates['/user-users/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
  }
```

```js
  onSignUpPress() {
    ....
    ....
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(() => {
          ....
        this.writeUserData(uid, name, email, phone);
        navigation.navigate("Profile");
      })
      ....
      .....
  }
```

but it's not working correctly any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase has many functionalities. Out of them two are authentication and real time database.

When you call `createUserWithEmailPassword` successfully, it automatically creates a UID of the user and stores the meta in Firebase Authentication.

You can now at point of time get this UID of this user when he is authenticated using `firebase.auth(). currentUser.uid` and then create a firebase reference where you want to save data `database.ref().child(path)` 
Use the `.set(object)` or `.push(object)` to save data.

Tip : Create your database architecture properly (see documentation) to be able to fetch the saved data properly.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```js
writeUserData(uid, name, email, phone) {
    const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    
  //You don't have to create key because userId is uniq value.
  return firebase.database().ref(`users/${userId}`).update({name, email, phone});
}

onSignUpPress() {
    ....
    ....
    // createUserWithEmailAndPassword promise resolve return userData!
      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then(userData => {
          ....
        this.writeUserData(userData.uid, name, email, phone);
        navigation.navigate("Profile");
      })
      ....
      .....
  }
```

and I don't get it why you try to update,

`updates['/user-users/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;`

even if you don't have postData at this moment!

You just set when user create post data like this

```js
writePostData(uid, postData) {
  const postRef = firebase.database().ref(`user-users/${uid}`);
  //this way is useful when key handling before push
  var push =  postRef.push();
  var key = push.key;

  return postRef.child(key).set(postData);
  
  //or just push
  
  return postRef.push(postData);
}
```

Comment: yes, I don't need updates, it's my wrong
I need to add user data to the database every new signup, every new account open
how can I do it?

Comment: you can call `writeUserData()` inside `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then((user) => this.writeUserData(user.uid, ...))` edited my post